# I cannot run my There is always an error sign next to my getline function and I don't know and understand how to fix it?

Tags: visual-c++

```
# include <iostream>
# include <cmath>

using namespace std;

int main();
{

  string color, plural noun, celebrity;
  
  cout << "Enter a color: ";
  getline(cin, color);

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: was meant to put ' { ' and ' { ' on a different line to ' int main ' and ' return 0 '

Comment: Format code!. Remove `;` after `main()`. Put `,` after `plural`

Comment: I have removed the ; after main() but my latter part of the code was

Comment: cout << "Roses are {color}" << endl;

Comment: cout << "{plural noun} are blue" << endl;

Comment: cout << "I love {celebrity}" << endl;

Comment: weird code but I am a beginner

Comment: What editor are you using? Modern editors should say where is problem in the code

Comment: Also you can't have variable name with spaces (`plural noun`). For example use underscore symbol instead of space

Comment: ok thanks will try that it says that I need to change 'getline' to 'std::basic_istream::getline but havtried that and the error is still present

Comment: Check [this](https://onlinegdb.com/S1SkrwfxS) errors in original code are fixed. Code compiles and can run

Answer (score 0):

There are errors in your code. Firstly, have you included `#include <string>` and `#include <iostream>` directives. Moreover, your code is as follows:

```
    int main();{
       string color, plural noun, celebrity;
       cout<<"Enter a color: ";
       getline(cin, color);
       return 0;
    }
```

However, if you notice, you have placed a semicolon (;) after the `int main` function, which might be giving you an error. 
Also, as you were discussing in the comment section, declare `plural noun` as `pluralNoun` or `plural_noun`; never leave a space. I addition, a string is never called as `cout<<"Roses are {color}"<<endl;`, strings have to be called as:

```
    #include<iostream>
    #include <string>
    int main();{
       string color, pluralNoun, celebrity;
       cout << "Enter a color: ";
       getline(cin, color);
       cout << "Roses are " << color << endl;

       cout << "Enter a plural noun: ";
       getline(cin,pluralNoun);
       cout << pluralNoun << "are blue" << endl;
       return 0;
    }
```

The code above and your latter code; if executed in the same way as above will definitely not give you an error. Hope this helped you overcome the problem! :)